# Mod_Rewrite not processing at all for JavaScript created dynamic URLs

Tags: javascript, html, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to make my URL's more user and SEO friendly by using mod_rewrite, I ensured that I have mod_rewrite available and enabled, and I've written a rule, but I'm not getting any of this working, below is what I have as a mod-rewrite rule for http://hoursofdev.bitnamiapp.com/searchResults.html?fLat=41.7420294&fLong=-72.7398906&tm=&dt=&ct=&loc=&runBy=query&locType=gps&q=Starbucks (This URL is being created by a javascript function)

to turn into

http://hoursofdev.bitnamiapp.com/Starbucks.html

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /searchResults.html?fLat=41.7420294&fLong=-72.7398906&tm=&dt=&ct=&loc=&runBy=query&locType=gps&q=$1 [L]
```

I've also ensured that in my httpd.conf file that I've allowed overrides.

Any direction to help me figure out why I'm not seeing any rewrite rules process would be a huge help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use an alias instead?  If it is only this one url making an alias is a bit easier:

```
Alias /Stabucks.html /searchResults.html?fLat=41.7420294&fLong=-72.7398906&tm=&dt=&ct=&loc=&runBy=query&locType=gps&q=Starbucks
```

Comment: What benefits does using alias have over rewrite?

Comment: Mod rewrite is useful when you need to change the url based on a lot of factors. Alias is a bit easier to use.  It is a bit less powerful than rewrite.  Both accomplish the same goal.  I always use Alias if it does the job and rewrite only as a last resort.  Rewrite also requires the rewrite module to be included so it may add extra processing overhead.

Comment: Please make this solution as accepted if this solves the problem.